# Как получить данные из JSON в контроллере Spring MVC?

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

**JS**

```
var json = {name: "chelovek", l_name: "chelovek2", age: 22}

$('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax("ajax",{
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json",

        data:'jsonDATA'+JSON.stringify(json),
        success:function(data){
            $('#value').html(data);
        }}
    );
});
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ajax")
public class ajaxcontroller {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hi(HttpServletRequest request){
        //вот так взял просто текст.а как взять json из параметра не знаю 
        AsyncContext str = request.getAsyncContext();
        return "SPRING MVC " + str;
    }
}
```

Как получить данные из JSON  в контроллере Spring MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зависимость `ackson-mapper-asl` `jackson-mapper-asl`

Модель:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private String l_name;
  private int age;
  // getters & setters ...
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", 
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
  logger.debug(person.toString());
  return new JsonResponse("OK","");
```

Response:

```
public class JsonResponse {

  private String status = "";
  private String errorMessage = "";

  public JsonResponse(String status, String errorMessage) {
    this.status = status;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }
}
```

ajax (example):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "addPerson",
  data: JSON.stringify({ name: "chelovek", l_name: "chelovek2", age: 22 }),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'OK') alert('Person has been added');
    else alert('Failed adding person: ' + data.status + ', ' + data.errorMessage);
  }
});
```